# Angular http request to apache server

Tags: angular, angular2-http

I develop an Angular 2 app, which should request an api from an external server, but also request to an local Apache server. The external api is requested with jsonp and works fine. For the local/internal server I want to use the http module, because, both applications will run on the same server.

My problem is, that actual while developing Angular runs on port 3000 and the Apache runs on port 80. If I only set the path to (e.g. /some/path) Angular is requested to port 3000 where no such part is to found. So I set the full address (http://localhost/some/path) but this will detect as cross origin request and is not allowed.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/gizmo/default-questions/get. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

How could I tell Angular that the regular http port will be 80. I think in future when all will be build it will be not problem, won't it? But I do not want to build and replace it for all corrections. Is this possible?

Comment: You need to configure the local server, not Angular

Comment: If the port is different it's already CORS. You need to configure your server to allow CORS requests.

Answer (score 0):

You should get your server to rewrite requests to avoid CORS issues.

```
core.gulp.task(TASK, () => {
  core.browserSync.init({
    port: core.config.browserSyncPort,
    server: {
      baseDir: (core.config.getMode() === 'start') ? ['.', 'build'] : ['build'],
      middleware: [
        rewrite([
          '^/api/(.*)$ ' + core.config.apiPhp + '/$1 [P]',
          '^/es/(.*)$ ' + core.config.esPhp + '/$1 [P]',
          '^[^\\.]*$ /index.html [L]'
        ])
      ]
    },
    open: false
  });
  core.browserSync.emitter.on('init', () => {
    // TODO: Should reload be here or inside timeout?
    core.browserSync.reload();
    setTimeout(() => {
      let link = core.link(`http://localhost:${core.config.browserSyncPort}`);
      core.mainHeading(TASK, `CTRL CLICK to open ${link}`);
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

You can do similar rewrites in Apache and NGINX. CORS is only enforced in the browser.

Comment: Must I add this to the angular service running on port 3000? Where can I set it?

Comment: Yes you set it on whatever is serving angular .. it might be Apache nginx or nodes browser sync ... all web servers allow server rewrites ... typically the logic is ... if the http URL request path starts /api then send the request to my api server, etc. The api server may then process it or proxy it to another server. My example code uses browser sync as server and connect modrewrite to do the rewrite